# Give test cases for a code that finds a power of a number

Tags: testing

Give test cases for a code that finds a power of a number

Guys this would seem to be the most easiest question to all the experienced members of this forum  but i being a neophyte can only put up these many test cases.

1.Check both values are inputted correctly or not.

2.Check for trivial case when x=0 then for any value of n it should return 0.

3.when n=0 it should always return 1 whatever x be.

4.check for negative values of x and n.
i)If n is negative then result should be always less than or equal to x.

5.Check first for smaller values of x and n i.e for 2,2 3,4 etc.

6.Now check for larger values of n and x and see the results.

**Are these test cases correct and Could anybody help me in adding more test cases.**

Comment: imo the code that actually calculates the power should not have to validate the inputs (as strings). That should be left to the caller of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Boundary Value Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis), I would test a combination of following x and n values *(asuming the inputs are integers)*.

- x: Low(Integer), -3, -1, 0, 1, 3, High(Integer)
- n: Low(Integer), -3, -1, 0, 1, 3, High(Integer)

Resulting in 7x7 possible combinations or 49 testcases.

> Boundary value analysis is a software
>   testing technique in which tests are
>   designed to include representatives of
>   boundary values. Values on the edge of
>   an equivalence partition or at the
>   smallest value on either side of an
>   edge. The values could be either input
>   or output ranges of a software
>   component. Since these boundaries are
>   common locations for errors that
>   result in software faults they are
>   frequently exercised in test cases.

**Testcases**

```
x        n
-1              -1
-1              -3
-1              0
-1              1
-1              3
-1              High(Integer)
-1              Low(Integer)
-3              -1
-3              -3
-3              0
-3              1
-3              3
-3              High(Integer)
-3              Low(Integer)
0               -1
0               -3
0               0
0               1
0               3
0               High(Integer)
0               Low(Integer)
1               -1
1               -3
1               0
1               1
1               3
1               High(Integer)
1               Low(Integer)
3               -1
3               -3
3               0
3               1
3               3
3               High(Integer)
3               Low(Integer)
High(Integer)   -1
High(Integer)   -3
High(Integer)   0
High(Integer)   1
High(Integer)   3
High(Integer)   High(Integer)
High(Integer)   Low(Integer)
Low(Integer)    -1
Low(Integer)    -3
Low(Integer)    0
Low(Integer)    1
Low(Integer)    3
Low(Integer)    High(Integer)
Low(Integer)    Low(Integer)
```

Comment: could you pls elaborate why you have chosen these specific numbers.

Comment: Low and High because they are at the very bounds of what an integer can contain. Should your program raise an error if the result doesn't fit in an integer/double anymore? -1, 0 and 1 because I consider them a special case. -3 and 3 as *normal* cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can still create testcases around the "valid input" and the way it is input:

1. text input
2. empty input
3. separator equal to locale? (,. etc.)
4. allow thousands sign?
5. thousands sign equal to locale?
6. how is negative input defined? - or ()
7. scientific numbers: 5e3, 5.6e4, 1,234,567e4, -12e34, 12e-34 etc.
8. numbers that are input in another unicode format (japanese, chinese, (real) arabic, bath etc.)
9. insertion of input by javascript (assuming web-application)
10. does validation work if javascript is disabled (assuming web-application)
11. fiddling with input put in http-post (assuming web-application)
12. what are the max numbers specified for a, b and result?

But you have to explain us more; what type of application are we talking about, what are the specifications, how is the input delivered, and do you have to test the input validation?

Comment: I do not have any idea about the application in which this code would be used as this was an interview question.

Comment: +1 @AutomatedChaos, it seems you assume to much, I assume to little <g>. Perhaps that was part of the interview excercise, asking additional information. Hope to see you at the Belgium Testing Days.

Comment: @Lieven: haha, yes, common knowledge in out department: to assume is to  make an _ass_ of _u_ and _me_. About the BTDs: maybe I'll be there, but I'm not much of a traveller :).